# Trying to center align a header image in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to make the banner image central on all sized screens...it looks fine on smaller screens but larger screens, it is pulling to the left.

Here's what I tried so far:

```css
.banner {
    padding-top: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="row">
      <img src="Banner3.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a **background** image...it's an actual inline image.

Comment: Since your question is pretty vague. I make a guess in the dark. remove, background position/size and your margin (all three are not needed) and add text-align:center;

Answer (score 0):

Just apply `display:block` and `margin:auto` to your image...And if you are using bootstrap3 use `center-block` class in image.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.banner {
  padding-top: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.banner img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code as I have modified it. 
Hope this will work for you.

```
.banner {
            padding: 0 40px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 40%;
            height: 25vh;
        }

    <!-- language: lang-html -->

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="banner">
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="http://bayavenue.ae/wp-content/gallery/diplomat-man-salon/IMG-20150513-WA0013.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                        </div
        </div>

        </body>
        </html> 









    <!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: your image is not centralize  ?

Comment: Way too many useless styles (there is no background image), margin is useless and actually I don´t even know what you try there. the last 4 lines of css are not needed aswell. only padding and text-align: center are needed.

Comment: tell me your images centralize  or not ?

Comment: yes but you use 9 lines of CSS while 2 do the same, that´s awfull

Comment: I have added the CSS in your existing CSS.  This will  work fine with every screen.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I've tried all the suggestions but I think my code is beyond repair now so I'm going to scrap it and start again! :)